# jump condition of a Green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

> Find the Green's function for the BVP $$y''-\frac1xy'=0 \ \ ; \ \ y(0)=y(1)=0$$

Clearly the operator is not self-adjoint, so the equivalent self-adjoint equation is $$\left(\frac{y'}{x}\right)'=0$$ Therefore the Green's function could be taken as $$G(x,t)=\begin{cases}A+Bx^2 & \text{if} \ \ 0\leq x<t \\ C+Dx^2 & \text{if} \ \ t<x\leq1\end{cases}$$ Now boundary conditions give $A=C+D=0$. Giving $$G(x,t)=\begin{cases}Bx^2 & \text{if} \ \ 0\leq x<t \\ C(1-x^2) & \text{if} \ \ t<x\leq1\end{cases}$$ Continuity of $G$ at $x=t$ gives $Bt^2=C(1-t^2)$. Also the jump discontinuity of $\displaystyle\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ at $x=t$ gives $$-2Ct-2Bt=t\implies B+C=-\frac12$$ Therefore $C=-\frac{t^2}2$ and $B=\frac{t^2-1}2$. Hence $$G(x,t)=-\begin{cases}\dfrac{(1-t^2)x^2}2 & \text{if} \ \ 0\leq x<t \\ \dfrac{(1-x^2)t^2}2 & \text{if} \ \ t<x\leq1\end{cases}$$ which is clearly wrong since the correct answer is $$G(x,t)=-\begin{cases}\dfrac{(1-t^2)x^2}{2t} & \text{if} \ \ 0\leq x<t \\ \dfrac{(1-x^2)t}2 & \text{if} \ \ t<x\leq1\end{cases}$$ I checked that taking the jump $1$ instead of $t$ would give the correct answer, but here in self-adjoint form the coefficient is $\displaystyle\frac1x$, whose reciprocal is what is taken as jump. What is possibly wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order that the solution to the non-homogeneous ODE
$$
y''-\frac{1}{x}y'=f(x), \qquad y(0)=y(1)=0 \tag{1}
$$
be given by
$$
y(x)=\int_0^1G(x,t)f(t)\,dt, \tag{2}
$$
the Green's function $G(x,t)$ must be the solution to
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)G(x,t)=\delta(x-t), \qquad G(0,t)=G(1,t)=0 \qquad(0<t<1). \tag{3}
$$
Eq. $(3)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G(x,t)\right)=\frac{1}{x}\delta(x-t), \tag{4}
$$
which implies
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t+\epsilon}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G(x,t)\right)dx
=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\delta(x-t)dx
=\frac{1}{t}
$$
$$
\implies \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\left.\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G(x,t)\right|_{t-\epsilon}^{t+\epsilon}=\frac{1}{t}
\implies \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}G(x,t)\right|_{t-\epsilon}^{t+\epsilon}=1. \tag{5}
$$
Therefore, the jump discontinuity of $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ at $x=t$ is $1$, not $t$.

Comment: Some of the references write that the jump is usually taken as the reciprocal of coefficient of highest order derivative term in its self-adjoint form (here this is $t$). Can you explain why this does not work in this case?

Comment: This happens because the differential operator $L:=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}$ and it's self-adjoint "cousin" $\tilde{L}:=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)=\frac{1}{x}L$ do not have the same Green's function. (Continue.)

Comment: The Green's function $G(x,t)$ of $L$ is the solution to $LG(x,t)=\delta(x-t)$ (subject to some boundary conditions), whereas the Green's function $\tilde{G}(x,t)$ of $\tilde{L}$ is the solution to $\tilde{L}\tilde{G}(x,t)=\delta(x-t)$. From these equations you can derive the jump discontinuity of $\partial_xG$ and $\partial_x\tilde{G}$ at $x=t$ by integrating their LHS and RHS from $t-\epsilon$ to $t+\epsilon$ and taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$. For $\partial_xG$, the jump is $1$; for $\partial_x\tilde{G}$, it's $t$.